# Stackview exchange or change order of views

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uistackview, stackview

Stackview containing array of textfield is embedded in scrollview. I want to change the order of the text fields on some actions. The way to remove and add the textfield results in distorted view. I also tested by removing from scrollview. Normal stackview too the exchange does not appear properly. I am using indexes to change :

---

`stackView.removeArrangedSubview(localityTF)`
`stackView.insertArrangedSubview(localityTF, at: 2)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is strange behaviour, but problem with the autolayout system, that should be updated before you can add localityTF back. Also don't forget that `removeArrangedSubview` does not remove the view from subviews array:

```
[self.stackView removeArrangedSubview:_label1];
[self.stackView setNeedsLayout];
[self.stackView layoutIfNeeded];

[self.stackView insertArrangedSubview:_label1 atIndex:2];   
[self.stackView setNeedsLayout];
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works great. Between curious to know , how did you figure this solution out. @Andrew

Comment: Then I tried remove and attach subview, I saw exception about constraints (then I attached the view back). I know that the Autolayout engine needs layout if you change constraints. After that I tried to add layout invocations and all has fixed.

Comment: I don't think you need to remove it first...[ insertArrangedSubview:atIndex:] will automatically rearrange the view if it's already in there.

Answer (score 9):

This is my solution in **Swift 3**. It can also be used *without defining the view in the stackview.*

Here I am changing the locations of the views of a Stackview with two views:

```
if let myView = stackView.subviews.first {
    stackView.removeArrangedSubview(myView)
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
    stackView.layoutIfNeeded()

    stackView.insertArrangedSubview(myView, at: 1)
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this bunch of code for replacing views in **UIStackView**, without refreshing any layouts.

```
if let objView = stackView.arrangedSubviews.first {
        objView.removeFromSuperview()
}
stackView.insertArrangedSubview(yourView, at: 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **horizontal** axis:

```
stackView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

If you use **vertical** axis:

```
import UIKit

enum VerticalSemanticContentAttribute {
    case forceTopToBottom, forceBottomToTop
}

final class VerticalStackView: UIStackView {
     var verticalSemanticContentAttribute:  VerticalSemanticContentAttribute = .forceTopToBottom {
        didSet {
             guard oldValue != verticalSemanticContentAttribute else { return }
        
             reverseArrangedSubviews()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        axis = .vertical
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    
        axis = .vertical
    }
}

// MARK: - Private functions
private extension VerticalStackView {
    func reverseArrangedSubviews() {
        let totalCount = arrangedSubviews.count
    
        for (index, view) in arrangedSubviews.enumerated().reversed() where index != 0 { // we don't need to reposition the last item. It's already in the right position
            removeArrangedSubview(view)
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            setNeedsLayout()
            layoutIfNeeded()
        
            let insertIndex = totalCount - index - 1
            insertArrangedSubview(view, at: insertIndex)
            setNeedsLayout()
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution perfectly works.
Call it every time and it will change the first stack element view with the last and vice versa.

```
  if let first = stackView.subviews.first, let last = stackView.subviews.last {
    stackView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    stackView.insertArrangedSubview(last, at: 0)
    stackView.insertArrangedSubview(first, at: 1)
    stackView.setNeedsLayout()
    stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
  }
```