# UITableView changing image and title position cell by cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering if there any possible way to create a table view with this style:

[image]

I have a dictionary contains title and image values, I need to create a cell one Image-Right / Title-Left and next vice versa. How can achieve something like this?

Comment: I would use `UICollectionView` instead if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a table view to achieve your requirement. you will need to follow the following steps.

**Method 1:**

- Create two table view cell XIB's one with left side label and right side image, the second one is with left side image and right side image.
- Keep same class of both the XIB's you have created but with different identifiers.
- In your Table view `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method implement following logic.

  ```
  extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return datasourceArray.count
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          if(indexPath.row % 0 == 0) {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RightLabelTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTablViewCell
              cell.model = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]
              return cell
          } else {
              let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LeftLabelTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTablViewCell
              cell.model = datasourceArray[indexPath.row]
              return cell
           }
         }
       }
  ```

> Note: You can use one class for TableViewCell with a different
>   identifier and design your xib's accordingly.

**Method 2:**

Flip your table view cell's content view in a such a way that they will swap in your UI.

add the following code into your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and also add else part of it because cell for a row may behave weirdly because of dequeing:

```
 extension UIView {
    /// Flip view horizontally.
    func flipX() {
        transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -transform.a, y: transform.d)
    }
 }
```

**Usage:**

```
cell.contentView.flipX()
cell.yourImage.flipX()
cell.youImageName.flipX()
```

Don't forget to add else part in `cellForRowAt` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `setAffineTransform` in this way:

• build up your `tableView` with one prototype cell that has an image in left and a label in right
• then do this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

    if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.contentView.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
        cell.YourImage.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
        cell.YourLabel.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
    }

    // do what ever you want ...

    return cell
}
```

also the best solution is defining 2 prototype cells but in your case this is a tricky and fast way to achieve your goal.

Comment: I think clean solution is to use 2 different prototype cells. But which one would you recommend performance point of view - A) using setAffineTransform on a common prototype cell or B) 2 different prototype cells?

Answer (score -1):

- Create one cell with 2 image and 2 label left and right
- when you went to left side image that time hide right side image same as in label.

cell

```
import UIKit

class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_left: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_right: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var img_right: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var img_left: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configure_cell(left:Bool)
    {
        if left{
            img_left.isHidden = true
            img_right.isHidden = false
            lbl_left.isHidden = false
            lbl_right.isHidden = true
            self.img_right.image = UIImage(named: "testimg")
        }else{
            img_left.isHidden = false
            img_right.isHidden = true
            lbl_left.isHidden = true
            lbl_right.isHidden = false
            self.img_left.image = UIImage(named: "testimg")
        }
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

ViewController

```
extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TestTableViewCell
        if (indexPath.row + 1) % 2 == 0 {
            cell?.configure_cell(left: true)
        } else {
            cell?.configure_cell(left: false)
        }

        return cell!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So how can I dynamically create this? Cell0 right left — cell1 left right— and repeat this?

Comment: ya sure wait minutes

Comment: @Mc.Lover check now

Answer (score -1):

There are actually many ways of doing this:

1. Create 2 cells. Have 2 cells like `OddTableViewCell` and `EvenTableViewCell`. You can choose with index path which to use in `cellForRow` method like:

   ```
   extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return dataArray.count
       }

       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           if(indexPath.row%0 == 0) {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EvenTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! EvenTableViewCell
               cell.model = dataArray[indexPath.row]
               return cell
           } else {
               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OddTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OddTableViewCell
               cell.model = dataArray[indexPath.row]
               return cell
           }
       }

   }
   ```
2. Have a single cell but duplicate views so you have 2 labels and 2 image views. Then hide them as you need to:

   ```
   class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

       @IBOutlet private var leftImageView: UIImageView?
       @IBOutlet private var rightImageView: UIImageView?

       @IBOutlet private var leftLabel: UILabel?
       @IBOutlet private var rightLabel: UILabel?

       var userImage: UIImage? {
           didSet {
               refresh()
           }
       }
       var userName: String? {
           didSet {
               refresh()
           }
       }
       var imageOnLeft: Bool = false {
           didSet {
               refresh()
           }
       }

       func refresh() {
           leftImageView?.image = imageOnLeft ? userImage : nil
           leftImageView?.isHidden = !imageOnLeft
           rightImageView?.image = imageOnLeft ? nil : userImage
           rightImageView?.isHidden = imageOnLeft

           leftLabel?.text = imageOnLeft ? nil : userName
           leftLabel?.isHidden = imageOnLeft
           rightLabel?.text = imageOnLeft ? userName : nil
           rightLabel?.isHidden = !imageOnLeft
       }

   }
   ```
3. Have a single cell with stack view. Add a label and image view onto the stack view. You can change order of items in stack view. Some promising answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327808/526828). The rest should be pretty similar to the second solution.

(4.) Also you could just use a collection view and have a label cell and an image cell.

Comment: you can use this from only one cell

Comment: @DivyeshGondaliya As the first sentence says "There are actually many ways of doing this". There are 4 of them explained in my answer. It is hard to tell from your comment but I assume you believe that having 1 cell is somehow better than having 2. That may seem so at least from maintenance perspective but from how table view works and how dequeuing works it is actually most likely better to have 2 dequeue identifiers.